# Best Practice for creating 3 layer architecture in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have designed the application in the following ways:

```
Form

UserManager manager = new UserManager();

bool result= manager.AddUser(txtName.text,txtPassword.text,txtEmail.text);


<App_Code>\BusinessLogic

Public Class UserManager
{
public UserManager()
{

}

public bool AddUser(string name,string password, string email)
{
    UserDB.AddUser(name,password,email);
}   
}


<App_Code>\BusinessObject
public class User       
{
private string _name;
private string _pass;
private string _email;

public string Name
    {
        get { return _name;}
        set { _name;= value; }
    }

public string Pass
    {
        get { return _pass;}
        set { _name= value; }
    }

public string Email
    {
        get { return _email };
        set { _email=value; }
    }


  }
  <App_Code>\BusinessObject\Collections

  public class UserList : List<User>
  {

  }

  <App_Code>\DataAccess

  public class UserDB
  {
public static bool AddUser(string name,string password, string email)
{
    //stored procedure call
}

   }
```

According to this design, please suggest is it correct way of doing it and something is wrong.
If it is wrong please suggest me how can i improve it.

I particularly want to ask, making the data access class static is good practice or not?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is more of a question for Code Review, but in short, your architecture is a pretty typical n-Layer architecture.

Comment: Avoid static. Instead, inject dependencies in constructor. Furthermore, read up on architecture topics. It all depends on your requirements.

Comment: is it webforms or mvc?

Comment: @JPHellemons: in what way does it matter in the context of this question?

Comment: @JPHellemons it is webforms

Comment: Check [this](http://pragdave.me/blog/2014/01/04/reactive-systems-have-no-top/) webblog. A `UserManager` class might be a code smell.

Comment: I prefer those classes in model folder or controller folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I miss here the interfaces that define the operations on BusinessLogic that will allow you to unit test the code.

```
public interface IUserManager{
    bool AddUser(string name,string password, string email);
}
```

About making the data access static, if it's a multithreaded environment like Asp.Net, you better don't, and follow the session per request strategy .

Comment: Thanks all for your valuable inputs